# custom exception and parsing message from exception

Tags: c#, compact-framework, oracle10g

```
ex.Message = "ORA-20586: SOME TEXT SOME TEXT.\nORA-06512: at \"RMM.LOKAC\", line 116\nORA-06512: at line 2"

catch (Exception ex)
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return false;
}

ex.Message = "ORA-20586: SOME TEXT SOME TEXT.\nORA-06512: at \"RMM.LOKAC\", line 116\nORA-06512: at line 2"
```

but i need to get just "SOME TEXT SOME TEXT". How can i read just text.

ORA-20586 means user error http://www.dbmotive.com/support/oracle-error-codes/?type=ORA&errcode=20586

Database is Oracle. How can i read just "SOME TEXT SOME TEXT" from this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of ways to extract the string. You may try String split,  regular expression split or string index search.

Comment: @senzacionale Sorry! I did't get what you want. Do you want to create custom exception at database base level or you want to define it in your program?

Comment: AVD i just want to print message. No need to be custom exception.

Comment: @senzacionale LINQ! How it parses a string? I don't see any valid reason to use LINQ.

Comment: so it is better to use substring and indexof

Comment: Agree! substring and indexof is better option.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to catch the exception, then write a more user friendly message. You never want to expose the underlying architecture of your application, if possible.

```
bool success = false;
try {
  // you code
  success = true; // Notice: Last call of  your try routine.
} catch (Exception ex {
  if (-1 < ex.Message.IndexOf("ORA-20586")) {
    MessageBox.Show("user error");
  } else {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
return success;
```